# how to know from a Site B, if the user is connected on the site A?

Tags: php, session

I have got a website and now i have to add a forum. The forum will be on a sub-domain of the site, but may be on an other server.

The user must sign-in only from the website, to be connected on the forum. If the user try to see the forum without sign-in on the website, , he'll be redirect to the the sign-in page form the website, if he is yet connected from the website, he'll can see the site.

My question is how to kwow on the forum ,if there is a session open by the user on the website??? how do they both communicate ? (cookies stuff?, webservice?, and how?)

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can be saved on the entire domain, thus allowing subdomains to read them.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/~rasmus/", ".example.com", 1);
```

.example.com should be replaced with your domain.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: Yeah with a `/` and not `/~domain/`

Comment: ok, with the communication by cookie, but so if i set a cookie on the website , the forum can read it and use it to connecte the user on him, but how to know if the session was expired on the website? or if the browser was closed without sign-out from the website?

Answer (score 0):

[Single Sign-On](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)?